# How can we run the excel macro of an existing Excel sheet using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hi i am trying to automatically open a excel workbook and run its macro for a web application using C# (visual studio) , can someone suggest if this is possible.

Comment: When you say "for a web application" - should the macro be executed on the client or on the server?

Comment: (Note: If the answer is "on the server", [this is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23265750/87698) and you should look for an alternative solution to your problem).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found a solution on web for how to run Excel macros of aldready existing application,
and runs its macro.

Here name of macro is : macro from workbook Macro.xlsm

Below is the code snippet :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


 namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //~~> Define your Excel Objects
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

        //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\d.b.venkatachalam\\Desktop\\Macro.xlsm");
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
        xlApp.Run("Macro");

    }
  }
}
```